# eclipse CDT /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l<libname>

Tags: linux, eclipse

this is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice.h>
#include <libimobiledevice/lockdown.h>
#include <libimobiledevice/installation_proxy.h>
#include <libimobiledevice/notification_proxy.h>
#include <libimobiledevice/afc.h>

int main(void) {
    idevice_t phone = NULL;
    char *udid = NULL;
    idevice_new(&phone, udid);
    puts("!!!hello!!!"); /* prints !!!Hello World!!! */
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

i installed libimobiledevice library and this is

```
#ls /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu | grep libimob
libimobiledevice.a
libimobiledevice.so
libimobiledevice.so.4
libimobiledevice.so.4.0.1
```

but why in configure CDT to use shared library like picture CDT error ?

`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibimobiledevice`

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `imobiledevice` instead of `libimobiledevice`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under libraries add `imobiledevice` instead of `libimobiledevice`. When you use `-lx`, linker searches for `libx.so`. In your case linker searched for `liblibimobiledevice.so` which it could not find.

Answer (score 0):

In Mars Eclipse, to add third party libraries it was only possible from 
C++/Build->Setting->Cross G++ Link-> Miscellaneous.

I wasted two hours adding libraries to by other methods, but this one worked for me.